# How does cancelCtx initialize its done property?

Tags: go, go-context

Does anybody knows how does context underlying works in Go?

I see that by calling WithCancel, `new CancelCtx` will be called

```
func WithCancel(parent Context) (ctx Context, cancel CancelFunc) {
    if parent == nil {
        panic("cannot create context from nil parent")
    }
    c := newCancelCtx(parent)
    propagateCancel(parent, &c)
    return &c, func() { c.cancel(true, Canceled) }
}

// newCancelCtx returns an initialized cancelCtx.
func newCancelCtx(parent Context) cancelCtx {
    return cancelCtx{Context: parent}
}
```

And in the newCancelCtx, cancelCtx construct is initialized and returned.

In the cancelCtx, the done property is just an instance from type of atomic.Value.
[image]

But at the stage of calling the cancel, done properly is turned into the chan struct{}
[image]

**So my question is how is done property in cancelCtx converted from atomic.Value to chan struct{}?**

Comment: [`Load`](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic@go1.20#Value.Load) returns an *interface* value. With interface values you can use [type assertions](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get the *dynamic* value stored *inside* that interface.

Comment: Thank you, do you know why type assertions can work? I mean does it mean atomic. Value can be converted into any type?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Type assertions are a language feature, so the question *"why type assertions can work"* is like asking why 1+1 equals 2. *"I mean does it mean atomic."* -- no, type assertions are neither atomic operations (AFAIK) nor are they part of the `atomic` package. *"Value can be converted into any type?"* -- no, `atomic.Value` cannot be [_converted_](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions) to any type, it can, however, be used to store values of any type. Note that type assertions and conversions are two quite different operations.

Answer (score 2):

`ctx.done` holds a `chan struct{}` in the `atomic.Value`.

In the code you included a picture of, you can see how the context code extracts the channel:

```
d, _ := c.done.Load().(chan struct{})
```

`c.done.Load()` retrieves the value (if any) stored in the `atomic.Value` (which has `any` type), and then type-asserts it to `chan struct{}`.

Comment: Thank you
`ctx.done holds a chan struct{} in the atomic.Value`
So how does this work? how to let atomic.Value holds a chan struct{}, is it done automatically?
Is this(holding a chan struct{}) the feature of atomic.Value?

Comment: `atomic.Value` is something in the standard library that you can look up. `ctx.done` gets a channel stored to it the first time you call `Done()` on a cancelCtx: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.20.1:src/context/context.go;l=413